# I have a user control on my Form1 but when i add a mouse event of the control it dosen't do anything why?

Tags: c#

```
private void lineGraph1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("test");
        }
```

I want that when I move the mouse over/on the control area it will show the message.
I downloaded the control dll from here :

```
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/274318/Line-Graph-Component-in-Csharp
```

Downloaded the demo and used the dll file there.
So I have now the control on Form1 and then I did on the control in the Form1 designer right click mouse properties events and double click on Mouse Enter but nothing when im moving the mouse over the control nothing happen.

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: Is your form focused? Do you have other mouse eventhandlers?

Comment: can you post the code where you are adding the eventhandler to the event

Comment: is `lineGraph1_MouseEnter` wired to control event?

Comment: Kevin I created the event from the Designer not in runtime code I went to Form1 designer then clicked on the graphline1 control then properties and events and mouse enter.

Comment: @user2065612 In order to have the event function, you need to add it as an event handler. Where do you do that? Also, is this WPF or WinForms?

Comment: It's winforms and as I wrote above I created the event from the Form1 designer in the linegraph1 properties > events > mouse enter

Answer (score 1):

Adding the method does nothing by itself. You have to add it as an event handler, such as with

```
lineGraph1.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(lineGraph1_MouseEnter);
```

The Form Editor does this for you when you select the MouseEnter event from the events dropdown at top right.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's due to the fact LineGraph has some controls over itself.
For example, if you put your onmouseenter event on the PlotArea control directly it will probably work fine.

```
    public PlotArea()
    {
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
        this.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(PlotArea_MouseEnter);
    }

    void PlotArea_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("test");
    }
```

Comment: Kwel well this is working but now when I move my mouse over the control I see the messageBox all the time it never stop I see the messageBox click on it and it show up again and again non stop. How od I fix it so it will show up only once ?

Comment: Kwel no it's not good I checked now again the event is activate once when the mouse is over the Form and I need it to be activated only when the mouse is over the control it self.

Comment: Once the popup is displayed, you left the control. Once the popup is closed, if your mouse is over the control, you'll re-enter it.
That's why you get this behaviour (you may add a MouseLeave event to check).
What do you mean by "the event is activate once when the mouse is over the Form" ? If the event is on PlotArea it should be triggered for this control only.